# Opinion on what my disk usage analyzer shows

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, disk, disk-usage

I recently installed Ubuntu and it's pretty slow on my machine: 12GB memory, 96GB SSD (where the OS run") and 1TB HDD
I've only installed anaconda-navigator and some extensions... nothing at all, so I can't understand why it is this slow!

Here's a disk analyzer capture of the HDD:
[HDD disk analyzed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK2pV.png)

Is it ok to have only 3.5GB used on 977GB with 88151 items (which seems a lot to me)?
And what about the picture? Why is it this much red?

Here's a disk analyzer capture of the SSD:
[SSD disk analyzed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8mqf.png)

Same questions here. /usr seems so full with only 7.7GB on 96GB

I attach also `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  9.6M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        87G  9.1G   74G  12% /
tmpfs           5.9G  115M  5.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       916G  4.0G  866G   1% /mnt/data
tmpfs           1.2G   12M  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

PS. Why do I have only 916GB if the hard disk is 1T? I know about the loss from decimal to binary measuring and about hidden features but in my last OS I had like 977GB so I did I lost more space?

This questions may be found useful to newbie like me, so please try to explain me if it's normal or if I have to do something while I install programs or to keep disk clean

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.  FYI: Questions asking for opinions are also off-topic here, this isn't a forum (Ubuntu Forums provides that service)

Comment: I noticed you changed your question from Debian to Ubuntu after the comment by guiverc. Please [edit] your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing the following commands...

`lsb_release -a`

`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sd* | grep -i trim`

`sudo lshw -C memory`